# B2C- Add button for changing email in custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I used this **[documentation](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup)** to split email verification and sign up for my sign up process.

I found in other questions that to skip the email changing step, just hide the email change button. My need is to create a button in the 4th step to allow to change the email.

Is there a way to give the same behavior to the button created with JS as the one hidden in the previous step please?

*PS : I tried to give it the same **id** and **class name** to the js button but it didn't work.*

Answer (score 0):

If you make the email field in 4th step not read only, and apply email.verified as the partnerClaimType (like default starter pack), it will force email verification if it’s changed on that page to anything other than what was pre populated.

Comment: If I add email field in 4th step and hide it, and apply email.verified as the partnerClaimType could this work?

Comment: Yes but you don’t need go hide it. We hide the verification controls for you if it’s prepopulated, and the controls only appear if the email changes.